# How can I increment a variable inside a function without using global variable please?

Tags: python, function, variables, global, increment

I need a way to print a timer every second and execute an action every 10 seconds.
The output of the program should be like below.

Timer is 1
Timer is 2
Timer is 3
Timer is 4
Timer is 5
Timer is 6
Timer is 7
Timer is 8
Timer is 9
Timer is 10
Action is executed
Timer is 1
Timer is 2
Timer is 3
Timer is 4
Timer is 5
Timer is 6
Timer is 7
Timer is 8
Timer is 9
Timer is 10
Action is executed
Timer is 1
Timer is 2
Timer is 3
.
.
.

The program should use threading. It should not be an infinite while loop.

I could have done it with below code but it uses a global variable. How can I do it without using a global variable and with a small amount of code like below.

```
import threading
import time

global MytTimer
MytTimer=0
def foo():
    global MytTimer
    MytTimer=MytTimer+1
    print("Timer is " + str(MytTimer))
    threading.Timer(1, foo).start()
    if MytTimer >= 10:
        MytTimer=0
        print("Action is executed")        

foo()
```

Comment: Create a class with foo as a method and MytTimer as a member variable.

Comment: please show me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by creating a class.

```python
import threading
import time

class count():
    def __init__(self, MytTimer):
        self.MytTimer = MytTimer
        self._run()
    def _run(self):
        threading.Timer(1, self._run).start() 
        self.MytTimer += 1
        print("Timer is " + str(self.MytTimer))
        if self.MytTimer >= 10:
            self.MytTimer=0
            print("Action is executed") 
        
a=count(MytTimer = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ticker thread that delivers values 1-10 to a queue, and then a consumer that executes an action whenever the value read from the queue is `10`:

```
import threading
import time
import queue

def foo():
    q = queue.Queue()

    def ticker():
        while True:
            for i in range(1,11):
                print(f'Timer is {i}')
                q.put(i)
                time.sleep(1)

    t_ticker = threading.Thread(target=ticker)
    t_ticker.start()

    while True:
        i = q.get()
        if i == 10:
            print("Action is executed")        

foo()
```

Comment: But there are while loops in this code. They consume valuable cpu time. I have much more things for cpu to do. Is there a way to do it without using infinite loops.

Comment: "They consume valuable cpu time." They do not, because of the semantics of the queue `get` and `put` methods. Calling `q.get()` blocks if there are no items available in the queue. Please take a look at the relevant docs (and of course the other loop is only excuting 1/second, so again it is not "consuming valuable CPU time").